# How to handle a question that asks many things

Tags: support, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007377/how-do-i-pass-values-between-templates-in-laravel). And in it he asks multiple questions, something like "Q1", "Q2"... "QN"

And should I need to flag it. Which flag would be appropriate to use?

Comment: I think **Duplicate** is right reason for close.

Comment: Too broad?  How specific do you what the question to be? If you analyze the question properly Q2 and Q3 solves Q1. Q4 is same as Q1 just including some tools to the problem... particular adding routes or controller. But they all refer to the same Question which is Q1.

Comment: Perhaps it was misleading to say 'Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4'

Comment: @MD ..really? Surely it's only duplicate if each one (or debatably at least one) of them is asked elsewhere. A q1, q2, qn question(s) is *not* inherently duplicate..?!

Comment: [This is a good example of lots of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014671/questions-about-php-mail-function)

Comment: Question is now edited. Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: related: [More than one question per post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275908/839601)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The *too broad* close reason is for these.