# I think I've been trolled. What should I do?

Tags: discussion, comments, scope, spam, comment-flags

The question in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263906/what-is-an-open-stereoscopic-image-format-for-any-production-google-cardboard-ap

Feel free to read the comments, TL;DR is: they say I'm asking for software recommendations, which, although welcome, is not the question, and then finally comment with a link that, if they had read the question, they would know is explicitly inapplicable.

If they didn't read the question, it doesn't make sense that they would keep commenting unless they were trolling. The main problem is that I assumed that they were trying to be helpful and fed them (my fault), and now there are several comments on the question that are not productive. Should I try somehow to remove these comments? Should I flag them?

Edit: Although an aspect of this situation is that there was a secondary question relating to potential answers to the primary question, this meta-question is about what happened in the comments, not [what to do about a question that is too general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things).

Comment: Your question does not appear to be a question _about programming._ While I personally am unsure where exactly your question could be asked, if anywhere, on the network, I do agree it's off-topic for Stack Overflow. _"what app should I recommend people use to view them?"_ reads as a recommendation request, though I see that's not the main thrust of your question. And no, just because your question is about file formats does not make it a question about programming.

Comment: It's _maybe_ on-topic, but it's _definitely too broad_.

Comment: I see no "trolling" by the other user in that question. They provided civil comments to indicate why they thought your question might not fit the site, and clarification when you responded to them.

Comment: Please ["assume good faith until the user has a documented history of not acting in good faith"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/55844).  Also, you might not want to assume that someone named Laurel is male, at least in the US.

Comment: Okay, so if it's really off topic, and there's actually no StackExchange forum for this question, what's the recommended course of action in that case?

Comment: @PaulRoub I would say that I did assume good faith, and repeatedly challenging a question that they did not read is an indication that Laurel is not acting in good faith, which has led me here.

Comment: If it's off-topic for SO, that's where our obligation ends. I have heard rumors that there are other sites on the internet, and that there are ones which allow you to search for those other sites.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I didn't ask here where to ask the question. What should I do with the OT question?

Comment: @PaulRoub You are correct in thinking I'm female. Hello everyone, I have arrived. And no, I was not trying to troll anyone.

Comment: Just so nobody misses it, you can see my full answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323206).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What's the first rule of Stack Overflow Club?
>
> **You don't talk about Stack Overflow on Stack Overflow.**

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/

This type of situation is the danger of leaving comments in addition to close voting (or downvoting). In fact, Stack Overflow pushed to create these metas in order to remove this type of discussion on posts with Jeff Atwood going so far as to say "Meta is Murder".

> "*Murder. I mean it. If enough productive work is replaced by navelgazing meta-work, then people will be killed. Or at least, the community will be.*" -Atwood.

http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/

So, overall, it is best to avoid meta type discussions of explaining why something was off topic in comments. Retorts and expansion quickly get tangential to the topicality of the question and as a result it can feel like the post was hijacked or trolled - which it wasn't.

Linking to an existing or new meta discussion which relates to the situation is generally better than trying to do it alone. There are *some* templates that certain users have for these situations, but overall the conversations should be reserved for meta.

Comment: This is good advice for the future. I was thinking that maybe I should open a meta discussion, but I was looking to avoid the meta effect (that cat has got out of the bag though). Fortunately, comments are easy to clean up.

Comment: We also get plenty of complaints about closures where "no one bothers to leave a comment", and we sure as hell don't need every close vote that anyone ever casts to get its own Meta post. One or two comments that expand on a close vote, or specify the particular problem with a question, is a perfectly good use of the commenting functionality. Sure, it takes a little self-control to avoid the "Retorts and expansion [that] quickly get tangential", but it can be done.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - I agree that we don't need a meta post per close vote. That is why there are canonicals to link to where there can be solid coverage of topics in one place - which as I note is where these conversations should take take place.

Answer (score 15):

I am the user in question. And I do not believe that my actions were trollish. I acted with two motivations in mind:

- My initial motivation was to get the question [on hold]. While some people find this facet of the system hostile, it is simply the way that we keep our site clean.
- My other motivation was to try and help. I consider myself a kind person, and I have recently begun to leave these types of comments because I think they might be helpful (I have gotten mostly positive responses).

Because I'm not a photography expert (as I said, I'd be active on Photo.SE if I were), I was not entirely sure what you were asking. Obviously, my initial reaction, that you were looking for photography advice, was pretty spot on, given the fact that you initially posted there.

Knowing that I'm not an expert photographer, it should make a little more sense why I thought that the link I provided was helpful and relevant. I actually continued to try to help you further in chat, too.

Because you were so insistent that your questioned *belonged* on SO, I tried to point out some of the other problems with what you were asking. Such as the fact that you were looking for a software recommendation.

We are a community of programmers, not photographers. As unfortunate as it is that you failed to get the response you wanted on Photo.se (despite how good the top voted answer seems), that does not mean that your question is on-topic here. Just because it is both "highly-technical" and involves computers does not mean that it is programming.

(Side note: the question where this all happened has been deleted, presumably by community consensus.)

Comment: Yeah, it can be hard to leave these types of comments without getting into some form of back and forth. That is why it is generally discouraged to leave meta type discussion on posts. I will expand in an answer here because the comment got a little drawn out.

Comment: I apologize for misjudging. I think @TravisJ hit the nail on the head.