# What could be done to discourage combining of multiple questions into a single post?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Maybe when multiple question marks are found in the entered text show a popup window with an explanation of how posting a list of questions reduces the chance of those questions to be answered?

I do not mean that using of multiple question marks per posting should be banned completely. The message should just inform the poster of all potential downsides of posting a combined question. They should be able to dismiss the popup and post the question anyway.

The message might mention that:

- the whole combined question could be closed if even a single question from the list is a duplicate
- separate parts of the list could attract separate down votes from different people
- people willing to answer just one part of the question may decide not to do so because they can not answer the whole thing

and so on.

Update:

I understand that the problem is deemed to be not significant enough to warrant any new feature development. But I do still believe the consensus is that it is a behavior to be discouraged. Can we at least get some official statement on this? Something tangible (maybe a topic in the *Help Center/Asking* section?) I could refer to in the comments?

Comment: vote to close as to broad if that makes the question so.

Comment: The tags I frequent do not get enough traffic to close even clear duplicates - so my votes have no effect most of the time

Comment: There's always downvoting or commenting to try to get the OP to improve or split their questions.

Comment: That's what I am doing currently and it feels like a chore. Thus this meta question

Comment: *and it feels like a chore* but you just said your tags don't get a lot of traffic. Try doing that in `javascript`... :P

Comment: downvote and move on. don't waste your time on it.

Comment: I am aware about my own options. I was hoping to start the discussion about ways to mitigate the problem (and so far everyone seems to agree that it is a legitimate problem) across the board and not on case by case basis.

Comment: I think I get it. You all are basically saying that it is my personal problem that the questions I personally find entertaining are rare enough that I want to be able to salvage as many of them as possible. The rest of you have the luxury of being able to quickly down/close-vote and move on to answering plenty of other better quality questions. Well sucks to be me

Comment: Its a legitimate question that is not specific to low-frequency tags; cramming in multiple questions at once I see daily in high velocity tags. But consider this: nobody is going to stop anyone from just removing the question marks, or put the upside-down question mark instead. You just can't prevent it, all you can do is moderate.

Comment: That's what I said - people answering questions in high velocity tags have that luxury of just ignoring the low quality questions. They still have enough of better quality questions available to them. So they just can't relate to my situation where I see less than handful questions per day and all of them are low quality. And with the measure I suggested I was hoping to target people genuinely willing to improve. All attempts to circumvent  the measure will be obvious and it will make the decision process (whether to close vote or not) even easier.

Comment: related: [How to handle a question that asks many things](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267059/839601)

Answer (score 4):

Problem is, multiple question marks aren't 100% indicative of multiple questions.  It's a strong heuristic, but it's no guarantee.

Above all, there's not much we *should* be doing to discourage this behavior outside of what we already do:  comment if we want them to clarify and/or pare their question down; downvote if it's not all that well-researched; vote to close if it is too broad, desperately needs clarity before some misguided soul attempts to answer, or is in fact opinion based.

Comment: I know it's not 100% - that's why I suggested just an informative message. And I got tired from having to explain that in comments over and over again. Also I see this pattern even from experienced users with tens of thousands rep points. I would like to see this point communicated more clearly by SE

Comment: @AlexP.:  If the behavior persists long enough, question bans get the message across *pretty* well that their questions aren't all that hot, which is why downvoting/voting to close is the best weapon we've got here.

Comment: close votes do not work in low traffic tags. the pattern I am seeing over and over is this - the question sits with a single close vote for a few days, then the OP posts a bounty then... the question gets bunch of upvotes. the end. still no answer (there might be few low quality attempts to snatch the bounty though)

Comment: All I am asking at this point is just some official statement on this