# Add "do not ask multiple (weakly related)? questions as a single question" clause to the how-to-ask page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It is quite often that one encounters a question, that may not be exactly bad, it may even be an interesting well-asked one, but that consists of 2, 3, 4 or even more separate (sub)questions.

While very very rarely those (sub)questions have high cohesion between themselves and separating them will do more harm than good, more often than not they are mostly separate questions, related only because the OP is interested in all of them at the same time.

In the latter case, AFAIU the appropriate action is to mark/close the question as ***Too Broad***, because the answer will usually be too big, and the post itself won't probably be helpful to/discoverable by future visitors. And even in the former case it is usually better to try to ask (sub)questions one by one.

All right, so far, so good, but our main asking guideline - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask doesn't mention that asking such questions is not always a best course of action. And the same with https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions if that gets closed as Too Broad.

**So, the proposal:** *Add "do not ask multiple weakly related questions as a single question" clause to the how-to-ask page.*

---

You will probably ask **why we need it** if [no one reads the how-to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/438719?noredirect=1) and why isn't it a duplicate of [What could be done to discourage combining of multiple questions into a single post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334862/what-could-be-done-to-discourage-combining-of-multiple-questions-into-a-single-p).

Because we will be able to at least send OPs to read it, unlike now, when `Do not ask multiple questions, read how-to-ask` comment only deserves the response of `Ehhm, there is nothing about one post - one question rule/guideline that I can see.`.

It is not some heuristic script with popup to discourage asking such questions. It is just a proper specification of what may work and what may not work in the QA format.

---

**EDIT:**

It seems that **`weakly related`** part is getting a bit of traction. Well, I agree that ideally there should not be any multi-questions at all, and cases where a question cannot be properly split are hardly probable.

In such a case there is a **stronger version**: *Add "do not ask multiple questions as a single question" clause to the how-to-ask page.*

It may be a bit too rigid for some rare edge cases, but it is probably better to handle them as exceptional cases, than to discuss on a meaning of `weakly related` and whether it applies for each particular question or not.

Comment: So I can ask lots of strongly related questions as a single question can I?

Comment: An example of a high cohesion compound question (that might not need to be closed) could be "Can you foo the bar in RuritaniaScript? If so, does the fooing support ANSI standard Marklar syntax directives?" An example of a low cohesion question might be "Can you foo the bar in RuritaniaScript? Why am I getting a Bad Boy Error when I try to close Hyper Studio 10,000 XL?"

Comment: @Robert even that first example seemed too broad. You're asking one question about how to do something, then a question about how that thing relates to a standard. Those seem like two very distinct questions that deserve their own posts, possibly referencing each other.

Comment: Do you really think the people who make this mistake comprehensively read the "How to Ask" page and determine that it is okay? Do you really think that spelling it out will have any effect? Or are you just wanting a definitive reference to point to that says it is not okay?

Comment: @CodyGray The latter one, because saying `read the how-to-ask` when there is nothing on multi-questions in it, seems somehow inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Questions that ask multiple questions are too broad for Stack Overflow regardless of how closely related they are. If a user has multiple on-topic questions that they would like to ask, they should ask those questions separately of each other.

Note that there is a difference between asking two closely related questions and asking something like:

> Is it possible to foo the bar using any built-method? If not, how would I go about fooing the bar otherwise?

Because this question is actually asking one question in the guise of two questions:

> How can I foo the bar?

If a built-in method is a solution then it is very likely to be posted as an answer, if not then they will get an answer on how to foo the bar anyways.

If the user wants to stress the importance of a built-in method, they can phrase it like so

> How can I foo the bar? I'm mostly looking for a built-in method, but if none exists then a custom solution will suffice.

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify the `weakly related` part. And do you agree that such clause (whether with `weakly` part or not) should be in the how-to-ask or not? Because the question wasn't about the merits of strong/weak cohesion between subquestion, but rather that there is nothing in the FAQ about "multi-"questions.

Comment: Why don't you just vote to close questions that ask multiple questions as too broad unless you can edit the two questions into one question without changing the intent of the post? I see no reason to add more complexity to a document that the users who post questions like this will never read. Users aren't going to magically start reading that document because we put a new bit of text there. I also believe the close banner sufficiently explains this.

Comment: I vote to close them, and there is no way to force posters to read it. But if someone **reads it** (usually after downvotes and `read how-to-ask` comment), I'd like to see it properly mentioned(see the latest edit).

Comment: ["if your question generally covers … and is ***a*** practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Well, it does it, but in an indirect, implied kind of a way, not in a `thou shalt strive not to` kind. I just like to comment `There are multiple questions asked here as a single question. Please, read how-to-ask`, and not feel after, that I'm sending OP on a fool's errand to read something that is not there.