# Is a question contain 2 separate but simple questions still too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I know it is an awful example of help vampire questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150465/what-does-sleep1000-and-systemcls-mean-in-c

I'm struggling if it is too broad,on one hand it has more than 1 question, on other hand 2 questions are looked easily answered, is flagging this question as 'too broad' misleading?

Comment: see also: [How to handle a question that asks many things](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those two commands do totally different things, and they don't even *appear* related to one another in the slightest. Even if they were good questions for the site (which they absolutely are not), there's no conceivable reason anyone in their right mind would ask them in a single post.

It's like asking what a for loop and a `main()` method are, or why the sky is blue and why chickens lay eggs, in the same post.

So the question is either unclear or too broad, for that reason. It doesn't matter how narrow or broad each individual subject is; every question is expected to have only one subject.

Comment: They are very related: both are commonly used by beginning C programmers who have no idea what they're doing, and both are terrible. :-)